# Workaround for VS2010: templates and overloaded functions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, overloading

I've code that are perfect build with mingw/g++ compilers but MSVC (2010) encountered error. Problem is overloaded functions and templates. May be somebody know workaround for MSVC? If workaround not exist (proof link is diserable) it also answer.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Function 
{
    virtual ~Function() {}
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

template <typename Class, typename ARG1>
struct MemberFunction1 : public Function
{
    typedef void (Class::*MEM_FUNC)(ARG1);
    explicit MemberFunction1(Class * obj, MEM_FUNC func, ARG1 arg1) :  m_object(obj), m_func(func), m_arg1(arg1) {}

    virtual void operator()()
    {
        (m_object->*m_func)(m_arg1);
    }

    Class *  m_object;
    MEM_FUNC m_func;    
    ARG1     m_arg1;
};

struct FunctionStorage
{
    explicit FunctionStorage(Function * func) : m_func(func) {}

    virtual ~FunctionStorage()
    {
        if (m_func)
        {
            delete m_func;
            m_func = 0;
        }
    }

    void call() { (*m_func)(); }
    Function * m_func;
};

struct MemberFunction : public FunctionStorage
{
    template <typename Class, typename ARG1>
    MemberFunction(Class * obj, void (Class::*func)(ARG1), ARG1 arg1) : FunctionStorage(new MemberFunction1<Class, ARG1>(obj, func, arg1)) {}
};


class Foo 
{
public:
    void funcWithParam(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "foo::funcWithParam(" << value << ")\n";
    }
    void funcWithParam(const char * msg)
    {
        std::cout << "foo::funcWithParam(" << msg << ")\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;    
    MemberFunction(&f, &Foo::funcWithParam, 5).call(); // problem here, if remove one of funcWithParam (stay only 1 function, no overload) all will be ok
    MemberFunction(&f, &Foo::funcWithParam, "hello").call(); 
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
main.cpp(65): error C2660: 'MemberFunction::MemberFunction' : function does not take 3 arguments
main.cpp(65): error C2228: left of '.call' must have class/struct/union
main.cpp(66): error C2660: 'MemberFunction::MemberFunction' : function does not take 3 arguments
main.cpp(66): error C2228: left of '.call' must have class/struct/union
```

[Here is ideone](http://ideone.com/ECi7e) build result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both overloads of `Foo::funcWithParam` match `void (Class::*func)(ARG1)` in `MemberFunction(Class * obj, void (Class::*func)(ARG1), ARG1 arg1)`, so the second parameter type is ambiguous: the compiler can't decide whether ARG1 is `int` or `const char *`.

Funny thing is if you invert the order of parameters in your templated constructor, i.e. make it like this:
`MemberFunction(Class * obj, ARG1 arg1, void (Class::*func)(ARG1) )` and also change your call site to this:
`MemberFunction(&f, 5, &Foo::funcWithParam)` 
it will work. The compiler first encounters the second parameter from which it deduces the type ARG1 is `int`. It then proceeds to the third parameter and because it now knows ARG1 is `int`, it knows which overload of &Foo::funcWithParam to select.

I am not sure what the behavior the standard dictates should be in this case, but one of the compilers surely has a bug, most likely VS2010.

Comment: Note that this is not entirely correct. The compiler should try to deduce `ARG1` from *all* possible places, and only if the deduction from all of them matches, use that. Changing the order should not influence template argument deduction. If you have an ambiguity in one part, and a match in another, then the match is used.

Comment: Well, I never said the behavior was correct. I was only pointing out the flawed way VS2010 deduces the parameter type in this case.

Comment: I meant to say that the explanation isn't entirely correct, sorry. It's not that the compiler takes the first deduction match, but tries to deduce all occurences of the template parameter.